# getting error in casperjs as "resource not found" for this ur?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to fetch the html for the url "https://stage.hiiro.co/auth/login" with the following coffeescript file code with casperjs

```
casper.start "https://stage.hiiro.co/auth/login", ->
  @echo @getHTML()
```

it gives me error that resource not found but this function works fine for all other urls that i try to access like https://www.facebook.com/, https://www.gmail.com/.

Can anybody guess why its not working?

And yes url "https://stage.hiiro.co/auth/login" works fine for browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a SSL error for this domain. Passing the `--ignore-ssl-errors=yes` option makes your script work fine.